# Is the BlogML project dead, and what are some alternatives?

Tags: blogml

Time and again BlogML comes up as the definitive standard for blog posts.

However, with no updates (information or releases) in over a year, and the official domain down for a number of months, the status of the project seems extremely questionable.

1) Is BlogML effectively dead? (Sub-question: despite that, is it still relevant? Id est, are platforms still programming with it in mind.)

2) Either way, what are some current alternatives in the way of standardizing blog posts/articles? From the Wikipedia article, the key feature, as I see it, is the ability to port blog content between engines and versions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the originator of BlogML and have maintained it on and (mostly) off over a number of years.  For the past couple of years I have been very focussed on coaching sporting teams and studying at university and have not given it any attention - other than to reply to emails that I receive.  I think it would be fair to say that the project itself has been - not dead - but hibernating :-)

There has been work going on by blogging engines, predominantly in the .NET space, to increase their integration with the spec.  Blog engines such as Microsoft's new open source offering (OrchardCMS), SubText, and FunnelWeb have all done work to improve their support for it.

I have recently started spending more regular time on the project and there are a number of initiatives I have planned to re-invigorate it and increase its adoption further (beyond the .NET world).

The first thing that has been done is to move the specification away from the .NET code library that was written to work with it.  BlogML (the spec) is now maintained on Google Code while the .NET library for working with BlogML is maintained elsewhere and is now completely separated.

I've created a discussion list to discuss BlogML:

```
 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/blogml-discuss
```

The next thing that I hope to deliver is a comprehensive set of documentation about BlogML.

Comment: +1 for the *excellent* news. The fact that the official domain was dead was what made me think it had completely gone under. Discussion list joined, and I'll be downloading the new version shortly.